Flutter 'Undefined name 'context' error all of a sudden
void showPaywall() async {
    setState(() {
      // _isLoading = true;
    });

    CustomerInfo customerInfo = await Purchases.getCustomerInfo();

    if (customerInfo.entitlements.all[entitlementID] != null &&
        customerInfo.entitlements.all[entitlementID]?.isActive == true) {
      setState(() {
        // _isLoading = false;
        alreadySubscribed();
      });
    } else {
      Offerings? offerings;
      try {
        offerings = await Purchases.getOfferings();
      } on PlatformException catch (error) {
        errorMessage(error);
      }

      setState(() {
        // _isLoading = false;
      });

      if (offerings == null || offerings.current == null) {
        // offerings are empty, show a message to your user
      } else {
        // current offering is available, show paywall
        if (!mounted) return;
        await showModalBottomSheet(
          useRootNavigator: true,
          isDismissible: true,
          isScrollControlled: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(25.0)),
          ),
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return StatefulBuilder(
                builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setModalState) {
              return Paywall(
                offering: offerings!.current!,
              );
            });
          },
        );
      }
    }
  }

I think it shouldn't make an error with context parameter since this method is in State object.
However, All of methods that receives context as BuildContext parameters are now making 'undefined name 'context''error.
It had no issues before and I'm sure I haven't done anything that would make this kind of issue.
It could be something related to the framework or configuration kind of things, I don't know...
Please let me know if you know how to fix this issue.
Thank you in advance!
I've tried cleaning cache files, reinstalling and downgrading flutter and dart extensions. and I found that this issue only occurs when methods outside of build needs BuildContext parameter.

try flutter clean followed by flutter pub get

I've already tried it but no progress... THX though!

I think you are missing the context key word.
only put:
context in the function parameter.
void showPaywall(BuildContext context) async {
    setState(() {
      // _isLoading = true;
    });

    CustomerInfo customerInfo = await Purchases.getCustomerInfo();

    if (customerInfo.entitlements.all[entitlementID] != null &&
        customerInfo.entitlements.all[entitlementID]?.isActive == true) {
      setState(() {
        // _isLoading = false;
        alreadySubscribed();
      });
    } else {
      Offerings? offerings;
      try {
        offerings = await Purchases.getOfferings();
      } on PlatformException catch (error) {
        errorMessage(error);
      }

      setState(() {
        // _isLoading = false;
      });

      if (offerings == null || offerings.current == null) {
        // offerings are empty, show a message to your user
      } else {
        // current offering is available, show paywall
        if (!mounted) return;
        await showModalBottomSheet(
          useRootNavigator: true,
          isDismissible: true,
          isScrollControlled: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(25.0)),
          ),
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return StatefulBuilder(
                builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setModalState) {
              return Paywall(
                offering: offerings!.current!,
              );
            });
          },
        );
      }
    }
  }

I hope it will work if don't then provide more code.

Well... Even though I put BuildContext parameter into the function, I can not deliver BuildContext to the function since It's keep saying 'undefined name 'context''. I think the point here is that I can not use context, which Stateful Widget's State object should provide.

can you provide the code of entire file?

I think it was an issue related to Flutter framework. I've just upgraded Flutter and all the errors are gone! Thanks anyway

I got this problem once and it was a problem with vsCode, but if you make 'flutter analyze' command (flutter compiler) in you folder and this error is shown your code are really wrong somewhere. So this is a first step to check if the problem is the code or the ide.

It was flutter causing the error. as I upgraded flutter, all the errors were resolved
